# C++ for_each calling a vector of callback functions and passing each one an argument

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, foreach

I'm fairly green when it comes to c++0x, lambda, and such so I hope you guys can help me out with this little problem.

I want to store a bunch of callbacks in a vector and then use for_each to call them when the time is right.  I want the callback functions to be able to accept arguments.  Here's my code right now.  The trouble is in void B::do_another_callbacks(std::string &)

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>



class A {
public:
    void print(std::string &s) {
        std::cout << s.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef boost::function<void(std::string&)> another_callback;
typedef boost::function<void()> callback;

typedef std::vector<callback> callback_vector;
typedef std::vector<another_callback> another_callback_vector;

class B {
public:
    void add_callback(callback cb) {
        m_cb.push_back(cb);
    }

    void add_another_callback(another_callback acb) {
        m_acb.push_back(acb);
    }

    void do_callbacks() {
        for_each(m_cb.begin(), m_cb.end(), this);
    }

    void do_another_callbacks(std::string &s) {
        std::tr1::function<void(another_callback , std::string &)> my_func = [] (another_callback acb, std::string &s) { acb(s); }
        for_each(m_acb.begin(), m_acb.end(), my_func(_1, s));
    }

    void operator() (callback cb) { cb(); }

private:
    callback_vector m_cb;
    another_callback_vector m_acb;
};

void main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::string s("message");
    std::string q("question");
    b.add_callback(boost::bind(&A::print, &a, s));
    b.add_callback(boost::bind(&A::print, &a, q));
    b.add_another_callback(boost::bind(&A::print, &a, _1));
    b.do_callbacks();
    b.do_another_callbacks(s);
    b.do_another_callbacks(q);
}
```

I thought I might be able to do something like this...

```
void do_another_callbacks(std::string &s) {

    for_each(m_acb.begin(), m_acb.end(), [&s](another_callback acb) {
        acb(s);
    });
}
```

But that doesn't compile in MSVC2010

Comment: The code below should work *in principle* - What error do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the long example is that `my_func(_1,s)` is evaluated right there and then. You need to use `std::bind` (or `boost::bind`) to invoke the function on each element in the range.

The alternative code that you posted does indeed work, but the whole example fails to compile because of the code in `do_callbacks`:

```
void do_callbacks() {
    for_each(m_cb.begin(), m_cb.end(), this);
}
```

`this` is of type `B*`, which is not callable. If you define a `result_type` typedef to match the return type of `operator()` then you could use `std::ref(*this)` instead. The following code compiles and runs under MSVC10:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>



class A {
public:
    void print(std::string &s) {
        std::cout << s.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef std::function<void(std::string&)> another_callback;
typedef std::function<void()> callback;

typedef std::vector<callback> callback_vector;
typedef std::vector<another_callback> another_callback_vector;

class B {
public:
    void add_callback(callback cb) {
        m_cb.push_back(cb);
    }

    void add_another_callback(another_callback acb) {
        m_acb.push_back(acb);
    }

    void do_callbacks() {
        std::for_each(m_cb.begin(), m_cb.end(), std::ref(*this));
    }

    void do_another_callbacks(std::string &s) {

        std::for_each(m_acb.begin(), m_acb.end(), [&s](another_callback acb) {
                acb(s);
            });
    }

    typedef void result_type;
    void operator() (callback cb) { cb(); }

private:
    callback_vector m_cb;
    another_callback_vector m_acb;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::string s("message");
    std::string q("question");
    b.add_callback(std::bind(&A::print, &a, s));
    b.add_callback(std::bind(&A::print, &a, q));
    b.add_another_callback(std::bind(&A::print, &a, std::placeholders::_1));
    b.do_callbacks();
    b.do_another_callbacks(s);
    b.do_another_callbacks(q);
}
```